# R:strsplit to add names to boxplot raises an error

Tags: r, boxplot, strsplit

I am using strsplit in R to add names to boxplot but this gives me an error.

```
strng <- "one%two%three"
tt <- strsplit(strng,"%",fixed=TRUE)
```

and then

```
boxplot(param~grp,data=snp,horizontal=TRUE,names=tt)
```

this yields

```
ls = list(c("one", "two",  :
  'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 3 != 1
Calls: boxplot ... boxplot.default -> do.call -> bxp -> do.call -> axis
Execution halted
```

the names argument requires a vector and strsplit returns a list. Are these incompatible?

If I do

```
boxplot(param~grp,data=snp,horizontal=TRUE,names=c("on","two","three"))
```

Then it is ok.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tt[[1]]` or `unlist(tt)` instead of `tt`

```
boxplot(param~grp,data=snp,horizontal=TRUE,names=tt[[1]])
```

`names` argument is expecting a vector and `tt` is a list, so you need to pass a vector not a list.